# HTTP streaming server behind nginx?

Tags: nginx, tornado, http-streaming

I'm trying to set up a HTTP streaming server I wrote with Tornado and python. Basically, it keeps the connection alive and occasionally flushes information out. It's a bit like long polling, except the connection isn't broken by the server.

Is it possible to put something like this behind nginx? I'm testing it from my browser, and I can't see any output until the server breaks the connection, then it's all sent at once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to turn proxy_buffering off for the streaming requests.  If all requests to the backend will be streaming, you can just use [proxy_buffering](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffering).  As it states in that entry, you can also manage buffering on a per-request basis by having your backend include an X-Accel-Buffering header to turn buffering on or off.

Comment: This is one of those salvationary comments about a totally obscure flag that I would have no other idea about. Bless you internet.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. Is the tcp_nodelay to Off? It is on by default unless turned off.
[Nginx Documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#tcp_nodelay)

Comment: Hm, that didn't do it. I should also mention that the Tornado app acts as expected when I access it directly, so I'm guessing nginx is doing some kind of buffering?